# Override Site Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site

We have a requirement to hide site permissions under gear icon for modern team site and replace it custom site permission action.

We are able to create a custom action in modern team site. However, we are unable to hide the existing OOB action. Please suggest to hide the same link.

Answer (score 0):

"Modern" site do not support as many customization options as "classic" site, so i don't think you can change the behavior.

Currently custom master page is not supported in the modern Site. You can refer to below article for more information about “custom modern experience in SharePoint Online”:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations

Supported and unsupported customizations for "modern" pages for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages